# java file upload on tomcat in hosting environment

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, web-hosting

On my personal computer, using Eclipse I have developed a java application to allow users to create their profile. In this application user logins which is just sql query based user name & password verification, After successful login user fills a profile form(createprofile.jsp), this form allows user to upload profile picture also, when user submits the form he gets redirected to another jsp(showprofile.jsp) which shows all saved details with uploaded picture.

Here I am saving all the form data in SQL table and uploading the profile picture in a folder D:\UploadedImages.

Tomcat is also running inside Eclipse as localhost, I have added a context entry in Tomcat server.xml, due to which my uploaded files in the above folder are available at url  http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/images/imagename.jpg. This helps me to add profile picture in showprofile.jsp like

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/images/imagename.jpg">
```

Now I want to upload this project the hosting server like HelioHost or godaddy. What I am not sure of that if I upload this project, what should be my permanent destination folder on hosting server to upload user profile pictures and how can I make them available at an URL like above.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need the relative path of the tomcat. catalinaBase is what you actually need. See the below example:

```
File catalinaBase = new File( System.getProperty( "catalina.base" ) ).getAbsoluteFile();
File propertyFile = new File( catalinaBase, "ProjectName/images/imagename.jpg." );
```

This should be your path.

If you need something different than this please update you question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, some questions I have. Is it going to return location of temp folder? Can I access files from this folder by a direct url? For how long  I can keep my files here?

Comment: No. Catalinabase is the first folder of you tomcat. If you want to access the temp then the url will be $CATALINA_BASE/temp. What do you mean with direct url? Regarding the time of keeping your files this is in your hand. It depends on how often you clean your tomcat. The server provider also plays his role.

Comment: I want to upload files to a location which is in my control like my public_html folder(on a typical hosting server like Heliohost). After upload I want to access my files from a URL like http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/images/imagename.jpg. I am sorry for asking you to spoon feed but I am really new to this.

Comment: I am sorry, you confused me. Please try to update your question accordingly in order to be clear what exactly the goal is.